# Webview not loading when redirecting to secure site(https://)

Tags: macos, https, response.redirect

I have a Webview in which I first load an URL, which will automatically redirect to https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll.

But the delegate functions

neither

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

nor

```
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse;
```

calling. So I got only a blank page.
Please help me in this.

I am using this function to load my Initial URL

```
 myReq=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myStr]];
    NSURLConnection *myConn=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myReq delegate:self];

    if(myConn){
        webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [webdata appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadData:webdata MIMEType: @"text/html" textEncodingName: @"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Removed the php tag. I added because We have the control over php also. So if I get any ideas then we can change the php code also.

Comment: How is this question related to WebView?

Comment: @ZsoltSzatmari How not? I loaded the URL in a WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by resending the request whenever the server failed to load.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame{
NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);

NSURLConnection *myConnn=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[[[sender mainFrame] provisionalDataSource] request] delegate:self];

 if(myConnn)
    NSLog(@"I got it");
```

}

And now the delegate functions are called. I can trust the server here.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
NSURLProtectionSpace *space = [challenge protectionSpace];
[space serverTrust];
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

}